# JavaFX jar is not loading with JAR file but loads fine when compiling code as application

Tags: java, javafx, jar, nullpointerexception, javafx-8

I can build and start the program just fine when compiling as an application in IntelliJ. However, nothing happens when I package and deploy and I try to double-click the jar. I decided to use Git Bash and run it from there and I see it is throwing a NullPointerException. Below is the JavaFX main class, my file structure, and the error that is being thrown.

Why am I getting a NullPointerException in the jar but works fine when I build and compile in IntelliJ?

Please let me know if I'm leaving any information out. Thanks!

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private Stage stage;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage){
        this.stage = stage;
        this.stage.setTitle("My JavaFX App");
        initRootlayout();
    }

    private void initRootlayout(){
        try{
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/main.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            scene.getStylesheets().add("css/default.css");
            stage.setResizable(false);
            stage.show();
        }

        catch(Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image: File Structure]

[image: Error being thrown]

Comment: Your first image is fine, but the second one should not be an image at all.  Post an exception stack trace as text, not as an image of text.  Copy the text from your terminal or command window, and paste it into your question.

Comment: Use `Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("view/main.fxml"));` instead of `Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/main.fxml"));`. That error (`Location is required`) has to do with the path.

Comment: @Cthulhu Since the Main class is in the unnamed package, there is no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your jar content mostly it is missing your resources folder.
if you make the jar using IntelliJ Artifacts make sure to include your resources folder in jar, File -> Project Structure -> Artifacts -> Select your artifact -> output layout tab -> [image: add copy of] -> Directory Content
 -> Select your resources folder. 
then rebuild your jar